# max:size method doesn't exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-validation

User needs to have ability to limit upload size and I set that variable and now validation is giving me problems. I have this in my validation

```
$var = Model::where('id','=','1')->first();
$up=$var->size;
```

Validation

```
$this->validate($request, [
        'file' => "'max:".$up."'",
        ]);
```

and it says

```
Method [validate'max] does not exist.
```

Comment: remove single quotes around `max`. It is a typo

Comment: nop it returns entire row I only need a string. and how to mark it then if not with single quotes because this only receives string

Comment: use this `'file' => "max:'".$up."'",` instead of this `'file' => "'max:".$up."'",` but i assume that this will also work `'file' => "'max:".$up,`

Comment: nop it doesn't work, first one because "max" needs to be part if the string and second the ' isnt closed

Comment: assume `$up = 10`. then validation string must be `'max:10'`. Are you sure that this will not work `'file' => "max:".$up` ?I added a single quote, by mistake, in my previous comment.

Comment: thanks now it's working... Can you give this as an answer so I can give you upvote and marked as solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume `$up = 10;` then validation string must be `'max:10'`.
Removing single quotes around the max will solve the problem.

So you have to change yout code from:

`'file' => "'max:".$up."'"` to

`'file' => "max:".$up`